# Why is the site called 'robotics beta'?

Tags: discussion

Isn't the site out of beta currently? Should the title reflect that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robotics is currently in public beta, as its [Area 51 profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020/robotics) shows. It will remain so until it reaches "critical mass", which I think is SE speak for "when we think you're ready". Have a look at the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) as well as the SO blog post [Does this site have a chance of succeeding?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/) for some more details on the process.

Comment: Oh, I thought I'd seen references that it was out of beta last December. Also, it seems to have a status of its own outside of Area51, unlike a couple of other Area 51 projects I follow. Fair enough then.

Comment: It came out of **private** beta in [November](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/a/76/131). During private beta (usually a couple of weeks max), only people who committed to the site during its commitment phase can post questions and answers to the site. This helps the site gain some content before it becomes available for everyone else. Once it's in public beta, there isn't much distinction between a beta and a full site, to be honest, A full site gets its own artwork and (sometimes) url but that's it, really.